# memory error in python for array of size 150 000

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I am trying to get the difference between each pair of element of 2 different numpy arrays (size: 1 X 150000). Here is the code used by me:

```
#the input numpy array are a and b
c = a - b.reshape((-1,1))

#For an array say a=np.array([1,2,7,6]) and b=np.array([1,2,7,6])
# c = array([[ 0,  2,  6,  5],
   [-2,  0,  4,  3],
   [-6, -4,  0, -1],
   [-5, -3,  1,  0]])
```

I understand why it gives memory error using this code. How to update the code so that I don't get the error?

I tried using `itertools combinations_with_replacement` to but still not able to get desired results.

Comment: Your `a` is (4,) not (1,4).  In any case `c` is (4,4).  Similarly a result of size (150000, 150000) is a bit big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to create an `150000 x 150000` array. I'm not sure which dtype you used but in case of int32 (4 bytes per number) and neglecting overhead of the array you try to allocate:

```
>>> 150000 * 150000 * 4  # bytes
90000000000
```

which translates to

```
>>> 150000 * 150000 * 4 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024  # Gigabytes
83.82
```

So if you don't have 84GB of (free) RAM you'll get a MemoryError for that operation.

With `itertools` it's even worse because you need a list which contains one pointer per element (on 64bit computers that's already 8 byte) and depending on your python version and computer each integer requires ~20-30 bytes:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
28
```

Essentially this would lead to a RAM requirement of:

```
>>> (28 + 8) * 150000 * 150000  # bytes
810000000000
>>> (28 + 8) * 150000 * 150000 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024  # Gigabytes
754.37
```

If you have enough hard disk storage you could try to calculate the distance from each point of the one array to all points in the other array and then save that to disk and then go to the next point in the first array and calculate all distances to all points in the second array, and so on. However depending on the way you store the values (for example if you save them in txt format) you might have an even bigger memory consumption. But that just allows you to calculate the distances - you won't be able to keep all the values in the RAM.

The most-straightforward solution for the MemoryError is to buy more RAM (you can calculate how much you need based on the above numbers). If that's not an option you need to change your approach.

Comment: "If that's not an option you need to change your approach." - Isn't that the main question?

Comment: @Caramiriel Not sure what you mean. I did add an alternative (just above the final statement): Writing intermediate results to the hard disk.

Comment: Well, I guess I will think of an alternative way of tackling the problem. Thanks for the advice on saving intermediate results. As @Caramiriel pointed out, I was looking for any straightforward approach if there is one.